# asio::async_write handler gets invoked after 3 seconds

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have been using boost::asio socket libraries for many years now. However, I am encountering one strange problem. I have a class that continuously sends data to another process. It reads from a queue, and sends it across until the queue gets empty. I have removed all those details from the below example to keep it simple. The function socket_write calls asio::async_write, which invokes writeHandler upon completion. I call the socket_write function again from the handler. This works flawlessly at low volume.

However, at high volume, things become weird. At first the program manages to execute 100 cycles of socket_write operation per second. After a minute or so, the writeHandler doesn't for return 3 seconds. Once it is back, another 100 cycles zip through in a second. Then again writeHandler doesn't return for 3 seconds. Once back, another 100 cycles zips through.

I am flummoxed! What can make writeHandler return 100 times a second, followed by 3 seconds of delay, and back to 100 times a second, followed by 3 seconds delay? This is a consistent pattern once it starts. The volume of data is not too high, each write operation doesn't send more than couple hundred bytes. I have timed the read operation on the receiving server too, it never takes more than few millisecond to read. The delay is only in the write operation.

```
class myclass
{
public:
    // other stuff
    void socket_write()
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(_socket,boost::asio::buffer(_writeVector),
            boost::bind(&this_type::writeHandler, shared_from_this(),
            pSession,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    void writeHandler(boost::shared_ptr<MessageSession> pSession, size_t bytesWritten, const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
          // stuff
        socket_write();   // Call the socket_write function again.
    }
};
```

Comment: This is weird, can you check with a debugger which line consumes 3 seconds inside `writeHandler`? Which protocol is it writing to? If it's a stream, it might be that buffer could be getting full, but then this is async...

Comment: Not inside writehandler. The writeHandler gets called 3 seconds after I execute async_write() function. It usually comes back in few milliseconds.

Comment: Try a debugger till someone experienced with boost asio comes along, 3 seconds are lot so debugger should tell you where they are going.

Comment: Found the answer myself. Regarding your advice on using debugger, have you tried putting a break point in boost code? It is a maze.

Comment: I already hinted that it might've been buffer in my first comment, if it wasn't then no matter how difficult it would've been, the sane choice was to use a debugger :p

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it for a while, I decided to see whether it was the buffer limit issue. So I looked up the send buffer size, it was at 64K. So I changed it to 1MB.

```
    boost::asio::socket_base::send_buffer_size option(1048576);
    _socket.set_option(option);
```

Solved!!! No more delay.